# PHP No such file or directory

Tags: php

I am new to php and seem to be having an issue with `session_start()`

To fix it on the main page of an ecommerce site I found, I inserted `session_save_path('sessions');` into the library/config.php and created a folder called "sessions" in the root of the store folder.  This seemed to work, but when I go into the /admin folder, I get all the errors I previously was on the front page.

I assume this is an issue with relative directories.  How would I get around this?

I've tried `session_save_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/hp/store/sessions');` but this gives me a 404 on the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know your directory structure inside out, it's probably best to specify an absolute path (which also requires some knowledge of where stuff is). Try using an absolute path:

```
session_save_path('/var/www/vhosts/example.com/src/sessions');
```

Depending on your Apache `DocumentRoot` can often be tricky if you're using shared hosting. If you would prefer to use relative paths, the only other way is to use trial and error until you find the correct path to your session directory:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/hp/store/sessions';
var_dump(file_exists($path));
```

Comment: I am hosted on ipage.  I tried using `/hermes/bosweb26b/b2252/ipg.<myloginname>/` which seems to be my path, but 404 on the admin folder. (works for the front page)